# flotr / protochart bar chart based on timestamps

Tags: javascript, prototype

i want to create a bar chart with flotr / protochart (tried both) but i can't get it to work properly. when doing the following, i get bars as small as a grid line.

```
Flotr.draw(
            $('workflow-chart'),
            [
                { label: 'D1', data: [[1291622400000, 3], [1291708800000, 8], [1291795200000, 7], [1291881600000, 0], [1291968000000, 5]] }
            ],

            {
                bars: {show: true, fill: true},


                xaxis: {

                    tickFormatter: function(t) 
                        { 
                            date = new Date();
                            date.setTime(t);

                            day = date.getDate() > 9 ? date.getDate() : "0" + date.getDate();
                            month = date.getMonth()+1 > 9 ? date.getMonth()+1 : "0" + (date.getMonth()+1);

                            return day + "." + month;
                        }
                }
            }
        );
```

this question is similiar to [Flotr x-axis date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057392/flotr-x-axis-date-time) but that hadn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the "mode" of the xaxis like [here](http://flotr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flotr/examples/prototype/basic-time.html).

```
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                tickFormatter: function(t) 
                    { 
                        date = new Date();
                        date.setTime(t);

                        day = date.getDate() > 9 ? date.getDate() : "0" + date.getDate();
                        month = date.getMonth()+1 > 9 ? date.getMonth()+1 : "0" + (date.getMonth()+1);

                        return day + "." + month;
                    }
            }
```