# Protype Javascript , Unable to return value from Java Array

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, flotr

I am unable to get the Date Values into X axis

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
            <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                    <title>Flotr: Basic Radar Example</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas2image.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvastext.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="flotr.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>


                            <div id="container" style="width:600px;height:400px;"></div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonData = [{date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06,low:95.96,close:100.34,volume:22088000},{date:'August 20, 2004',open:101.48,high:109.08,low:100.50,close:108.31,volume:11377000},{date:'August 23, 2004',open:110.76,high:113.48,low:109.05,close:109.40,volume:9090700},{date:'July 19, 2007',open:553.46,high:553.52,low:542.24,close:548.59,volume:6477800},{date:'July 20, 2007',open:511.90,high:523.18,low:509.50,close:520.12,volume:16026500},{date:'July 23, 2007',open:519.01,high:520.00,low:512.15,close:512.51,volume:6227900}];


     var priceData = [];


      for(var i = 0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
      priceData.push([i, jsonData[i].low]);
    }


    var f = Flotr.draw(
        $('container'),[ priceData],{
            xaxis:{
                tickFormatter: function(n)

                {

                        var date = jsonData[n].date;

            return date; 



                }
            }

        }
    );



    </script>



            </body>
    </html>
```

It is throwing an Error as 
detailed error: jsonData[n] is undefined

Comment: Java array? Methinks you should edit your title.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like 'n' is not what you think it is.
on a side note as your using prototype, you can simplify your code using:

```
var priceData = jsonData.pluck('low');
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057392/471559) I can see that `tickFormatter` is passed a timestamp, not an index. `jsonData[n]` is undefined because `n` is not the index you think it is.

The linked question also seems to have a good solution too, you should try that.
[Flotr x-axis date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057392/471559)

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir , I have defined this way xaxis:{
   tickFormatter: function(n)
   
   {
   
   // doesn't know how to proceed here 
       
   
   
   }